# How to create a vector brush tool in WebGL ? (like Clip Studio or Concepts)

Tags: javascript, vector, drawing, webgl, brush

I'm working to create a Drawing tool on the browser using WebGL. I would like to be able to edit and modify strokes. So it's about having something like Clip Studio or Concepts. I think they use some kind of vector brushes but hard to tell because it looks a lot like "stamp" brushes.

For now, I'm using the classic "stamp" method using DeCasteljau algorithm to cut Bezier into lines and then I use Bresenham's line algorithm to get points coordinates that will construct my line. Those points are then rendered as vertices, passed in a buffer and renderer as gl_POINTS, with a custom shader to apply textures and wanted effects.

This is working nicely but not really efficient since the 2 previous algorithm are done by the CPU. Also I'm having trouble with opacity but that's a different matter. So if I'm keeping all those strokes editable, it's making millions of points to update which is killing the render time. So definitely not the right approach.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that those apps cache the results of all the strokes but the stroke currently being edited so that while editing a particular stroke they just (1) draw the texture that has everything visible behind the stroke being edited (2) draw the stroke being edited (3) draw the texture of everything in front of the stroke being edited (4) draw the stroke widgets. Most of those apps also eventually get too slow and have options to not render the strokes for when the scene gets too complex (outline mode)

As for how you draw it's hard to know without seeing examples of the exact feature you're trying to implement. There are various kinds of brush strokes. A few that come to mind are

(1) Stroking to look like caligraphy (1 color, sharp or blurry, oval brush)

My guess is they build polygon mesh that represents the outline of the stroke. Given vertices down the stroke line with an extra parameter of 1.0 and edge vertices with an extra parameter of 0.0 (or something like that) it seems like it would be relatively easy to write a shader that shades the polygon with various parameters for blurriness.

The hard(er) part is handling corners. Most structured drawing programs have options for how to handle the corners.

(2) Stroking by stamping an image (like putting leaves along a stroke)

This sounds like the method you chose but usually these types of strokes have options for how often to stamp (like number of stamps per unit) and options for randomness in things like orientation, offset from the spline, or even multiple different stamps.

(3) Stroking by repeating a brush (like a patterned ribbon or chain links in a chain)

This one feels again like generating a polygon based on the stroke and setting the texture to repeat though I'm sure it's not that simple if you actually want to do chains as the chain can only bend at link joints.

Anyway, a few references that might be related

- [Drawing lines is Hard](https://mattdesl.svbtle.com/drawing-lines-is-hard)
- [Approximate General Sweep Boundary of a 2D Curved Object](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2e92/f0c0c0d28bcc75a57d68732bb1506eb505b0.pdf)
- [Simulating Artistic Brushstrokes Using Interval Splines](http://people.csail.mit.edu/sarasu/pub/cgim02/cgim02.pdf)
- [Brush Painting Algorithms](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~uffe/xjobb/BrushPaintingAlgorithms.pdf)
- [Simulating High Detail Brush Painting on Mobile Devices](https://adrianblan.co/files/Simulating_High_Detail_Brush_Painting_on_Mobile_Devices.pdf)
- [Rendering Vector Art on the GPU](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems3/part-iv-image-effects/chapter-25-rendering-vector-art-gpu)
- [GPU-accelerated Path Rendering](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/devzone/devcenter/gamegraphics/files/opengl/gpupathrender.pdf)
- [Efficient GPU Path Rendering Using Scanline Rasterization](http://kunzhou.net/zjugaps/pathrendering/GPUpathrendering.pdf)
- [A Realistic 2D Drawing System](https://keithp.com/~keithp/talks/cairo2003.pdf)

Unrelated but [gl.POINTS is argruably going to fail eventually as it's only required to support points of size 1.0 and behavior outside the viewport is inconsistent](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-drawing-without-data.html#pointissues)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I've studied most of those approaches but it's very hard to know how good they actually are until you code them. 
My brushes tries to be realistic, so color, sharp, blurry, textured etc... Basically trying to have a Procreate looks. I would love to be able to edit them too.

When you say you think they cache the result, how would you do this ? With a render target (framebuffer or fbo or whatever, i'm a bit confused with those terms) ? Then how do you put them back together ?

gl.POINTS weakness should not be a problem for now, but good to know, thanks.